# How to start spring server usinng github actions

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I am using github actions to deploy the spring boot application on EC2. It works great but in the end it is terminating the server process. Is there any way to make github runner not to kill this process so that server doesn't stop.

[image: Here is the image of the workflow]

In short, I want to deploy the spring boot application just using github action, without using docker or any other container.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify something. Are you trying to run the sprint boot application in github actions as a host? Or are you trying to deploy your sprint boot application into an EC2 in aws?

Comment: I am trying to deploy it, the thing happening here is that the deployment is successful but how do I start the server after the deployment, @EdwardRomero.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have all the aws credentials figured out due to being able to upload the code into the ec2.

Normally when you us a docker image there is a starting command like

```
  ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar application.jar"]
```

that starts your application. So we just need to figure out how to accomplish this same task after you application is deployed to your ec2.

In your case i would do a send-command to the ec2 so that it starts the application. The caveat here is that the command we send needs to run in the background so that we can make sure that app keeps running in the background after send command returns a response

```
aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
    --parameters 'commands=["nohup sh -c java $JAVA_OPTS -jar application.jar &"]' \
    --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=i-1234567890abcdef0" \
    --comment "Start Application"
```

The idea here is that it will run the java start application in the background and return. The nohup command allows you to run the command in the background and event if session is logged off then it will keep running

Resources:
[nohup command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)
[aws send command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html)